# Android ClassNotFoundException immersive_mode

Tags: android, android-studio

I have got an sample android project. I can compile and make project by using Android Studio. I can generate .apk file. When i run it on the phone, error occurs, message is **"Unfortunately, ...App has stopped"**

When i run the project by Android Studio, error occurs and the error message is `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.edgescreen.immersive_mode.ImmersiveModeActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.edgescreen-1.apk"`

And i see another error in "AndroidManifest.xml" file even though i can compile and generate ".apk".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.edgescreen"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.edgescreen.immersive_mode.ImmersiveModeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".provider.edgescreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.samsung.android.cocktail.action.COCKTAIL_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.cocktail.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/single_cocktail" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".list.CocktailListAdapterProvider" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.samsung.android.cocktail.action.COCKTAIL_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.cocktail.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/list_cocktail" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".list.CocktailListAdapterService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.samsung.android.cocktail.mode"
        android:value="edge_single|edge_extended" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

the error is at `android:name="com.example.edgescreen.immersive_mode.ImmersiveModeActivity"` ... message is "Cannot resolve symbol immersive_mode".

I have checked that `immersive_mode` folder and the class `ImmersiveModeActivity` is located correctly. Can anyone give me some suggestion to solve this, please?

Comment: Can you place your entire manifest file ?

Comment: @naranz ... yes entire manifest is added to post

Comment: do you have the package com.example.edgescreen.immersive_mode which contains ImmersiveModeActivity class? I guess you have immersive_mode package that contains ImmersiveModeActivity.

Comment: when you hold ctrl and try to click on the path inside the manifest does it open the activity class? You can also click on the 'application' tab in the manifest and see if any component is not defined well

Answer (score 0):

By default your android apk file takes com.example.edgescreen package to run the `Activity`, and your `Activity` placed in immersive_mode package, so it'll not able to find your `Activity`, try following kind of stuff in manifest file instead of previous one, and clean and re-build project once again and run it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.edgescreen"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".immersive_mode.ImmersiveModeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hope this helps you. And please accept the answer is you found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try android:name=".immersive_mode.ImmersiveModeActivity"? And your Activity path is correct?